# Spark RDD mapping one row of data into multiple rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a text file with data that look like this:

```
Type1 1 3 5 9
Type2 4 6 7 8
Type3 3 6 9 10 11 25
```

I'd like to transform it into an RDD with rows like this:

```
1 Type1
3 Type1
3 Type3
......
```

I started with a case class:

```
MyData[uid : Int, gid : String]
```

New to spark and scala, and I can't seem to find an example that does this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you want something like this?

```
rdd.flatMap(line=>{
  val splitLine = line.split(' ').toList
  splitLine match{
    case (gid:String) :: rest => rest.map(x:String =>MyData(x.toInt, gid))
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is complaining the first argument to MyData is not Integer

Comment: Yes, it would be a string. You'll have to cast to an int. I updated my answer to a naive implementation

Comment: probably basic scala question: I tried _.toInt, but it is not compiling

Comment: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toInt)

Comment: Updated my answer but I'm not in front of a compiler so cannot guarantee it