# transform the RDD with list column , into multiple rows in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Hi I have a RDD table like `with case class userInfo(userID: Long, day: String, prodIDList: String)`

```
userA, 2016-10-12, [10000, 100001]
userB, 2016-10-13, [9999, 1003]
userC, 2016-10-13, [8888, 1003,2000]
```

And I want to transform this into like ,

```
userA, 2016-10-12, 10000
userA, 2016-10-12,100001
userB, 2016-10-13,9999
userB, 2016-10-13, 1003
userC, 2016-10-13, 8888
userC, 2016-10-13, 1003
userC, 2016-10-13, 2000
```

Anyone has ideas how I can do this by using RDD command in Spark??

When I look at the relevant post in stack overflow in [Spark RDD mapping one row of data into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008169/spark-rdd-mapping-one-row-of-data-into-multiple-row), it suggests me to use flatmap, but I don't know how to apply this to my case because I am spark beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Array(("userA", "2016-10-12", Array(10000, 100001)),
             ("userB", "2016-10-13", Array(9999, 1003)),
             ("userC", "2016-10-13", Array(8888, 1003,2000))))
val resultRDD = dataRDD.map{ case (a, b, c) => ((a, b), c)
}.flatMapValues(x => x).map{ case ((a, b), c) => (a, b, c)}
```

Comment: Thanks John, this is what I want!

Comment: awesome! could you click the check button to accept this as the correct answer? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with the dataframe APIs, you can convert the RDD to a dataframe and use the "explode" function . It will be something like below.

```
> import spark.implicits._
> val df = rdd.toDF()
> val exploded = df.withColumn("prodID", explode(col("prodIDList")))
```